# How to get the Unix Image in Docker Hub

Tags: docker, unix, virtualbox

I searched on Docker Hub but couldnt find any Unix Image. I want to work with Unix Command line to test few commands. There are two ways

1. Run a Unix Docker Image
2. Download a Unix iso file and run it in virtual Box

Is any of the two possible ?
Is Unix iso available like other linux fedora etc.
Any links ore references for the same ?

Comment: eg ubuntu, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "Unix". Do you actually mean the original Unix? My understanding is that their last release was 30 ago (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unix_history-simple.svg). I'm doubtful that the original Unix can be run in a docker container. Keep in mind docker uses the kernel of the host system. So even if you would get an archive of the Unix userland and place it into a docker image, I would expect these tools to fail as soon as they try to access some kernel functionality that is specific to the Unix kernel.

Comment: Regarding using the ISO file, you might have more luck with that. Check the answers here for more information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33750/is-there-a-way-to-download-pure-unix

Comment: Like oracle solaris, FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few free Unix distributions available, one being BSD.

An BSD image is available on Docker Hub:

https://hub.docker.com/r/auchida/freebsd/